# Download file in Angular on click of button

Tags: angular

Using HTML5, we can download file using Download.

In Angular, how to download file from a specific known location when a button is clicked.

Comment: You can also use the `download` attribute in angular or you install a npm package like [filesaver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver).

Comment: <a target="_self" href="pathOfFile" download="nameoffile">

Answer (score 0):

Try this give your actual file path into href and filename into download attribute.

```
<a target="_self" href="pathOfFile" download="nameofFile">
```